# Can't get AngularJS to generate POST request on save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, model-view-controller, haml, crud

I'm trying to do some really basic CRUD using Rails and AngularJS. I've got my app displaying data correctly and I can delete entries, but I cannot get my UI for creating a new entry to work at all.

I've tried a couple different schemes, but here's my view for creating a new District:

```
%form{"ng-controller" => "DistrictsController"}
  %label
    Name
    %input{"ng-model" => "district.name", type:"text"}
  %button{"ng-click" => "save()"}
    Save
```

When I click "Save" nothing happens. Not even a POST request is attempted. I'm using the default save function in my service/controller. However, I know the click handling is working because if I overload save in my DistrictsController like so:

```
  $scope.save = function () {
    alert('Hellooooo');
  }
```

I get an alert when I click the button.

Also, it's worth pointing out I can create a new district if I generate the POST request to /ops/districts/ in a REST client with the parameters:

```
key='district[name]', value='foo'
```

Why is the default save function not generating any request at all?

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something... *"Why is the default save function not generating any request at all?"* What default save function?

Comment: Well for remove, for instance, I can call district.$remove({id: district.id}). I didn't define this anywhere, it's default.

Comment: I helped Cap' in real life & now he understands that there's no default $scope.save(), just a Resource.$save()